# Iterating a string using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write this code in a more pythonic way using map, reduce, filter. Can someone help me with that.

This is a simple piece of code which assigns a total value to a string based on it's position in the string. 
For example, for the string `abaacab`

```
a b a a c a b
1   2 3   4    occurrence of a
  1         2  occurrence of b
        1      occurrence of c
1+1+2+3+1+4+2 = 14
```

---

```
import sys
check, total = {}, 0
for i, v in enumerate(sys.argv[1]):
    if v in check:
        check[v] += 1
    else:
        check[v] = 1
    total += check[v]
print(total)
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: Your code has unnecessary things, for example to use enumerate, besides that you do not explain the purpose of your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Pythonic way to solve this problem is `check = collections.Counter(sys.argv[1])` and `total = len(sys.argv[1])` (if I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, which is not necessarily the case). I'd never use `map`, `reduce` or `filter` here (nor in most Pythonic code), so I have no idea why you're asking about them.

Comment: It's a simple piece of code that assigns a value to a string based on its position in the string. The point isnt the code but how can the process of looping, adding to a dict and cumulative total be done pythonically.

Comment: @MelissaStewart Actually, no. It seems to be counting elements. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: This is tagged python3 but `reduce` is only in python2.

Comment: Is `enumerate` really necessary? The index `i` is never used.

Comment: For what use do you `enumerate`?

Comment: @puzzlepalace `reduce` is in Python 3, but it has been moved into the `functools` module...

Comment: Pythonic doesn't mean "replace my for-loops with comprehensions wherever possible".

Answer (score 4):

If you want to calculate the result in the way you're currently doing it, I think your current code is about as Pythonic as it can be (the only exception is the unnecessary `enumerate` call).

However, I think there's a better way to find your `total` than adding up the counts as you make them. The part of the total contributed by each value can be calculated directly from the final count of that value (it's a triangular number). This means you can count the values in one go and figure out the total at the end.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import sys
import collections

counts = collections.Counter(sys.argv[1])
total = sum(n * (n+1) // 2 for n in counts.values())
print(total)
```

Comment: A slower but easier to understand alternative to `n * (n+1) // 2` would be `sum(range(n+1))`.

Comment: @Rawing Is that really slower and not optimised? (I can't run it myself, currently.)

Comment: @Rawing yeah, but then you might as well just sum as you count.

Comment: The thing here to note is that OP wanted a demo of comprehensions, not an answer that was computationally efficient... anyway.

Comment: Oh if OP literally meant map, reduce, and filter, then none of these answers cut it.

Comment: @Coldspeed as per the comments, I think the question is *how to do it Pythonically*, which is sort of tolerated in the Python tag as far as opinion-based questions go, but "using a comprehension instead of a for-loop" != "pythonic"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oftentimes "pythonic" tends to have a positive correlation with hindered readability....

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
val = {v : sys.argv[1].count(v) for v in set(sys.argv[1])}
total = sum(val[k] * (val[k] + 1) // 2  for k in val)
```

3 lines... 1 import and 2 lines of vanilla python.

The first line creates a mapping of chars to counts. Then, the second line finds the sum of sequence for each character inside a list comprehension, with a second `sum` to total the sums of each character.

Output:

```
val: {'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
total: 14
```

Caveat: This is not efficient, since it calculates counts for each character (linear complexity).

Answer (score 1):

SO willing, here's another answer that *actually* does what you want as you want it. Python3 compliant, haven't tested on Python2.

```
from functools import reduce, partial
total = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x: x * (x + 1) // 2,  map(partial(str.count, sys.argv[1]), set(sys.argv[1]))))
print(total)
```

Output

```
14
```

---

Breaking it down:

`partial(str.count, sys.argv[1]) ---- (1)` defines a higher order function which the `map` will apply to `sys.argv`. This way, your counts are created. A dict is not needed for the final answer so it is not created.

`map(---(1)---, set(sys.argv[1])) ---- (2)` applies the partial function (1)

`map(lambda x: x * (x + 1) // 2, ----(2)----) ----(3)` takes the counts generated by (2) and then applies AP to get the sum.

`reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, ----(3)----)` tops it off with a summation of the sums from (3).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I would say your code could be made more Pythonic is by using a `Counter` object instead of a regular `dict`, which streamlines the actual counting being performed by the `dict`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> s = "abaacab"
>>> total = 0
>>> for c in s:
...     counts[c] += 1
...     total += counts[c]
...
>>> total
14
```